# How to share the same window object with the other web page that is opened using window.assign method

Tags: javascript

I have a web application opened with some origin http://first-web-app.com. It has its own window object and has some properties associated with it. From this application I will open another application using window.location.assign(http://second-web-app.com).

The problem is that the new page is creating its own window object and cannot access the properties/methods of the first page’s window object. I have a lot of functions on the first window object and can’t copy/keep them on the second one as this is the project requirement.

How to implement this scenario where the second page needs to access the first page’s window object?

Comment: You can NOT. Look at https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication

Comment: @JanPfeifer — This isn't about cross-window communication. It's about persisting data between two different pages in the same window.

Comment: Yes @Quentin! You are correct. It is not a cross window communication but a communication between two different pages of a same window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

Each time a page is loaded (be it the same page or a different page) you are running a *new application*. Different applications do not share variables.

If you was to persist data between different pages then you need to store it somewhere that is explicitly designed to persist.

If your pages shared the [same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) then you could use one of the [Web Storage APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API). That doesn't seem to be the case here so you'll need to transfer the data through some other mechanism, such as a web service that you access using [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) (and which uses [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) to share the data between origins).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @quentin. Instead of implementing web services, i have decided to go with creating a new library which includes the shared functionalities. Both the web applications can now install it and use the same methods.